# How to import classes implementing annotation @RunTestInLooperThread

Tags: asynchronous, testing, junit, realm, looper

I'm new to Realm and Android Programming. I have a problem implementing JUnit tests of async login (`SyncUser.loginAsync`).
When I run the test I get the error:

"Asynchronous login is only possible from looper threads. Realm cannot be automatically updated on a thread without a looper."

To solve this problem I found that I should import these classes (Adding Annotation `@RunTestInLooperThread` for tests to be run in a Looper):

```
import io.realm.rule.RunInLooperThread;
import io.realm.rule.RunTestInLooperThread;
import io.realm.rule.TestRealmConfigurationFactory;
```

But the package `io.realm.rule.*` is not found.

What I should do to import those classes?

I'm using gradle plugin `io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.0`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Those classes are being used by our internal instrumentation tests. They are not distributed in a public manner.

You can however, copy them directly from our Github repo if you need them: 
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/realm/realm-library/src/testUtils/java/io/realm/rule